# Accessing plugins from fragments and vise versa

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-fragment

I'm trying to add a fragment to a plugin in order to have 
information added to the plugin without touching the latter.

However, the problem I experienced is that I can access resources
that are in the plugin from the fragment but not the other way 
around.

This is how I'm fetching the resource and the manifests of both
projects. The resource file "patch.xml" is in /src folder.

**test.plugin2:**

main class:

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RetrieveResource ma = new RetrieveResource();
        ma.retrieve();
    }
}
```

RetrieveResource:

```
public class RetrieveResource {

    public RetrieveResource(){

    }

    public void retrieve(){
        URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("patch.xml");
        System.out.println(url);
    }
}
```

url is always null.

manifest.mf:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Plugin2
Bundle-SymbolicName: test.plugin2;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime;bundle-version="3.7.0"
```

build.properties

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .,\
```

**test.fragment2:**

manifest.mf

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Fragment2
Bundle-SymbolicName: test.fragment2
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Fragment-Host: test.plugin2;bundle-version="1.0.0.qualifier"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Export-Package: test.fragment2.classes
```

build.properties

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .,\
```

What is missing or where did I go wrong?
Is it even possible to access fragments from plugins?

**PROBLEM SOLVED:**
In my tests, I was starting the test.plugin2 project as in 
"java application" mode. Since the fragment and plugin have
to be merged at runtime, the application have to be started
in "eclipse application" mode and there will be no problem 
fetching the resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FileLocator.find` (in `org.eclipse.core.runtime`) to search for resources in a plugin and fragments.

```
Bundle bundle = ... your plugin Bundle

IPath path = new Path("patch.xml");

URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, path, null);
```